# Imgur API - How do I retrieve all favorites without pagination?

Tags: python, imgur

According to the [Imgur Docs](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/account#account-favorites), the "GET Account Favorites" API call takes optional arguments for pagination, implying that all objects are returned without it.

However, when I use the following code snippet (the application has been registered and OAuth has already performed against my account for testing), I get only the first 30 JSON objects. In the snippet below, I already have an access_token for an authorized user and can retrieve data for that username. But the length of the returned list is always the first 30 items.

```
username = token['username']
bearer_headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token['access_token']
}
fav_url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/account/' + username + '/' + 'favorites'
r = requests.get(fav_url, headers=bearer_headers)
r_json = r.json()
favorites=r_json['data']
len(favorites)
print(favorites)
```

The requests response returns a dictionary with three keys: status (the HTTP status code), success (true or false), and data, of which the value is a list of dictionaries (one per favorited item).

I'm trying to retrieve this *without* pagination so I can extract specific metadata values into a Pandas dataframe (id, post date, etc).

I originally thought this was a Pandas display problem in Jupyter notebook, but tracked it back to the API only returning the newest 30 list items, despite the docs indicating otherwise. If I place an arbitrary page number at the end (eg, "/favorites/1"), it returns the 30 items appropriate to that page, but there doesn't seem to be an option to get all items or retrieve a count of the total items or number of pages in advance.

What am I missing?

Postscript: It appears that none of the URIs work without pagination, eg, get account images, get gallery submissions, etc. Anything where there is an optional "/{{page}}" parameter, it will default to first page if none is specified. So I guess the larger question is, "does Imgur API even support non-paginated data, and how is that accessed?".

Comment: In the documentation, there is a `page` parameter, maybe you should try with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paginated data is usually used when the possible size of the response can be arbitrarily large. I would be surprised if a major service like Imgur had an API that *didn't* work this way.

As you have found, the `page` attribute may be optional, and if you don't provide it, you get the first page as your response.

If you want to get more than the first page, you will need to loop over the page number:

```py
data = []
page = 0
while block := connection.get(page=page):
  data.append(block)
  page += 1
```

This assumes Python3.8+ due to the `:=` assignment expression. If you are on an older version you'll need to set `block` in the loop body, but the same idea applies.